# Как изменить xml

Tags: android, разметка, android-xml

Есть квадратное изображение флага xml:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
android:width="21dp"
android:height="15dp"
android:viewportWidth="21"
android:viewportHeight="15">
<path
      android:pathData="M0,0h21v15h-21z"
      android:strokeWidth="1"
      android:fillType="evenOdd"
      android:strokeColor="#00000000">
    <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
      <gradient 
          android:startX="10.5"
          android:startY="0"
          android:endX="10.5"
          android:endY="15"
          android:type="linear">
        <item android:offset="0" android:color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <item android:offset="1" android:color="#FFF0F0F0"/>
      </gradient>
    </aapt:attr>
  </path>
  <path
      android:pathData="M6,0h15v5h-15z"
      android:strokeWidth="1"
      android:fillType="evenOdd"
      android:strokeColor="#00000000">
    <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
      <gradient 
          android:startX="13.5"
          android:startY="0"
          android:endX="13.5"
          android:endY="5"
          android:type="linear">
        <item android:offset="0" android:color="#FF12833B"/>
        <item android:offset="1" android:color="#FF0D7332"/>
      </gradient>
    </aapt:attr>
  </path>
  <path
      android:pathData="M6,10h15v5h-15z"
      android:strokeWidth="1"
      android:fillType="evenOdd"
      android:strokeColor="#00000000">
    <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
      <gradient 
          android:startX="13.5"
          android:startY="10"
          android:endX="13.5"
          android:endY="15"
          android:type="linear">
        <item android:offset="0" android:color="#FF262626"/>
        <item android:offset="1" android:color="#FF0D0D0D"/>
      </gradient>
    </aapt:attr>
  </path>
  <path
      android:pathData="M6,5h15v5h-15z"
      android:strokeWidth="1"
      android:fillType="evenOdd"
      android:strokeColor="#00000000">
    <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
      <gradient 
          android:startX="13.5"
          android:startY="5"
          android:endX="13.5"
          android:endY="10"
          android:type="linear">
        <item android:offset="0" android:color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <item android:offset="1" android:color="#FFF0F0F0"/>
      </gradient>
    </aapt:attr>
  </path>
  <path
      android:pathData="M0,0h6v15h-6z"
      android:strokeWidth="1"
      android:fillType="evenOdd"
      android:strokeColor="#00000000">
    <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
      <gradient 
          android:startX="3"
          android:startY="0"
          android:endX="3"
          android:endY="15"
          android:type="linear">
        <item android:offset="0" android:color="#FFFF323E"/>
        <item android:offset="1" android:color="#FFFD0D1B"/>
      </gradient>
    </aapt:attr>
  </path>
```

Как его превратить в круг

Comment: редактор искать для него, либо в самом android studio есть. есть же да?  :)

Comment: да но я не понимаю как закруглить

Comment: искать, тут без вариантов. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66567783/is-there-a-way-to-get-round-circle-icon-on-android-studio

Comment: обратите внимание на android:shape в <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
...
<foreground>
   <inset
       android:insetBottom="18dp"
       android:insetLeft="18dp"
       android:insetRight="18dp"
       android:insetTop="18dp">
       <shape android:shape="oval">
           <solid android:color="#0000FF" />
       </shape>
   </inset>
</foreground>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185103/how-to-define-a-circle-shape-in-an-android-xml-drawable-file

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: Так же можно квадрату задать радиус и он станет кругом.